# FullCalendar display event half of day (Event width)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I want to display the **event start half of day and end of half day or full-day for few events**. Currently all event works full day in a month.

**At the same time is it possible to display event width based on start and end time?**

[image: event-display]

I have tried below stack reference code. Comment for further clarification.

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {        
    var containerWidth = jQuery(element).offsetParent()
    .siblings("table").find(".fc-day-content").width();
    // half a day
    var elementWidth = parseInt(containerWidth / 2);
     // set width of element
    jQuery(element).css('width', elementWidth + "px");
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'resourceTimeline' ],
    header: {
      left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    displayEventTime: true,
    displayEventTime: true,
   displayEventEnd: true,
   timeFormat: 'h:mma',
    defaultView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
 editable: true,
    resources: [ {
        "id": "a", "title": "Auditorium A"
    }
    
    ,
    {
        "id": "b", "title": "Auditorium B"
    }
    
    ,
    {
        "id": "c", "title": "Auditorium C"
    }
    ,
 {
        "id": "e", "title": "Auditorium E"
    }    
    ,
    
    ],
   events: [
    {
     id: 1,
     className: "HalfClass",
     resourceId: 'a',
     title: 'Taufik1',
     start: "2019-09-03 06:00",
     end: "2019-09-05 12:00",
     description: '' 
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     resourceId: 'b',
     title: "Smith", 
     color: "#F6BB42",
     start: "2019-09-06",
     end: "2019-09-08"
    },
    {
     id: 3,
     resourceId: 'c',
     title: 'Austin',
     start: "2019-09-04",
     end: "2019-09-08",
     description: '' 
    },
    {
     id: 4,
     resourceId: 'd',
     title: 'Wong Ling',
     color: "#DA4453",
     start: "2019-09-04",
     end: "2019-09-06"
    }
    
   ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/interaction/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-common/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: parseFloat instead of parseInt for one.

Comment: @Icewine Updated Is it possible to change width based on time?

Comment: Its not a built in function but you could use eventRenderer callback function to modify them. Like changing the appearance with the elements style object.

Comment: Okay. do you have any idea .How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using the built-in API is to set a shorter slot duration - this will give more space for the calendar to show the times of your events accurately.

```
slotDuration: {
  "hours": 12
},
```

divides the calendar up into half-day slots instead of full-day ones, introducing a time component to the view which then allows a more fine-grained display.

I've also (optionally) used `slotLabelInterval` and `slotLabelFormat` to improve the header display from what it would default to with that `slotDuration` setting, so it looks neater.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-display and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting for documentation.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    plugins: ['interaction', 'resourceTimeline'],
    header: {
      left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    displayEventTime: true,
    displayEventTime: true,
    displayEventEnd: true,
    timeFormat: 'h:mma',
    slotDuration: {
      "hours": 12
    },
    slotLabelInterval: {
      "hours": 24
    },
    slotLabelFormat: [{
        month: 'long',
        week: "short",
      }, // top level of text
      {
        weekday: 'narrow',
        day: 'numeric'

      } // lower level of text
    ],
    defaultView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
    editable: true,
    resources: [{
        "id": "a",
        "title": "Auditorium A"
      }

      ,
      {
        "id": "b",
        "title": "Auditorium B"
      }

      ,
      {
        "id": "c",
        "title": "Auditorium C"
      },
      {
        "id": "e",
        "title": "Auditorium E"
      },

    ],
    events: [{
        id: 1,
        className: "HalfClass",
        resourceId: 'a',
        title: 'Taufik1',
        start: "2019-09-03 06:00",
        end: "2019-09-05 12:00",
        description: ''
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        resourceId: 'b',
        title: "Smith",
        color: "#F6BB42",
        start: "2019-09-06",
        end: "2019-09-08"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        resourceId: 'c',
        title: 'Austin',
        start: "2019-09-04",
        end: "2019-09-08",
        description: ''
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        resourceId: 'd',
        title: 'Wong Ling',
        color: "#DA4453",
        start: "2019-09-04",
        end: "2019-09-06"
      }

    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/interaction/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-common/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I added a bit for you to see. I wont write all the code but it should give you an idea of where to start.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'resourceTimeline' ],
    header: {
      left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    displayEventTime: true,
    displayEventTime: true,
   displayEventEnd: true,
   timeFormat: 'h:mma',
    defaultView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
 editable: true,
    resources: [ {
        "id": "a", "title": "Auditorium A"
    }
    
    ,
    {
        "id": "b", "title": "Auditorium B"
    }
    
    ,
    {
        "id": "c", "title": "Auditorium C"
    }
    ,
 {
        "id": "e", "title": "Auditorium E"
    }    
    ,
    
    ],
   events: [
    {
     id: 1,
     classNames: "HalfClass",
     resourceId: 'a',
     title: 'Taufik1',
     start: "2019-09-03 06:00",
     end: "2019-09-05 12:00",
     description: '' 
    },
    {
     id: 2,
     resourceId: 'b',
     title: "Smith", 
     color: "#F6BB42",
     start: "2019-09-06",
     end: "2019-09-08"
    },
    {
     id: 3,
     resourceId: 'c',
     title: 'Austin',
     start: "2019-09-04",
     end: "2019-09-08",
     description: '' 
    },
    {
     id: 4,
     resourceId: 'e',
     title: 'Wong Ling',
     color: "#DA4453",
     start: "2019-09-04",
     end: "2019-09-06"
    }
    
   ],
      eventRender: function(info) {

       // option 1:
       if(info.event.classNames[0] == "HalfClass"){
        info.el.setAttribute("style", "width: 105px;");
       }
       
       //option 2:
       // set it by targeting the $(".HalfClass") directly.
            
      }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/core/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/interaction/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-common/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/resource-timeline/4.2.0/main.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: This one static width. Based on the time we can't able to set dynamic width?